# R gWidgets toggle item value in menu list

Tags: r, gwidgets

How do I create a toggle value item inside a gmenu object? For example, in Eclipse menu, **Project -> Build Automatically** option, I can toggle its value by clicking on it. A check mark will be displayed in front of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `gWidgets2` this can be done. Here is an example that can be improved upon:

`library(gWidgets2)
w <- gwindow()
mlist <- list(file=list(
                  cb=gcheckbox("check", parent=w, handler=function(h, ...) print(svalue(h$obj))), 
                  act=gaction("hi", handler=function(...) print("hi"), parent=w), 
                  gseparator(parent=w),
                  rb = gradio(letters[1:3], parent=w, handler=function(h, ...) print(svalue(h$obj)))
                  ))
gmenu(mlist, cont=w)`